# Cleanest ruby code to split a string with specific rules

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, hash

imagine an array like this

```
[
"A definition 1: this is the definition text",
"A definition 2: this is some other definition text",
"B definition 3: this could be: the definition text"
]
```

I want to end up with the following hash

```
hash = {
:A => ["A definition 1", "this is the definition text", "A definition 2", "this is some other definition text"], 
:B => ["B definition 3", "this could be: the definition text"]
}
```

I'm creating a glossary, with a hash of each letter of the alphabet with definition arrays.

I'm pretty new to Ruby so what I have looks really inelegant and I'm struggling on the split regex of the line on the colon so that the 3rd line only splits on the first occurrence.

Thanks!

**Edit**
Here's what I have so far

```
def self.build(lines)
    alphabet = Hash.new()

    lines.each do |line|
      strings = line.split(/:/)
      letter = strings[0][0,1].upcase
      alphabet[letter] = Array.new if alphabet[letter].nil?
      alphabet[letter] << strings[0]
      alphabet[letter] << strings[1..(strings.size-1)].join.strip
    end
    alphabet
  end
```

Comment: To learn how to use `split()` on only the first occurrence, see my answer, or rather see the [documentation for `split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165) and look at the `limit` parameter.

Comment: bah thanks, that limit param has eluded me till now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided raw_definitions is your input:

```
sorted_defs = Hash.new{|hash, key| hash[key] = Array.new;}

raw_definitions.each do |d|
  d.match(/^([a-zA-Z])(.*?):(.*)$/)
  sorted_defs[$1.upcase]<<$1+$2
  sorted_defs[$1.upcase]<<$3.strip
end
```

Comment: nice pretty much worked, $2 is missing $1, can u make the 2nd match start at the beginning again?

Comment: Yeah that is why I added $1+$2 try that out.  This revision produces the correct output, tested in IRB.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's a purely-functional alternative:

```
defs = [
  "A definition 1: this is the definition text",
  "A definition 2: this is some other definition text",
  "B definition 3: this could be: the definition text"
]

hash = Hash[
  defs.group_by{ |s| s[0].to_sym }.map do |sym,strs|
    [ sym, strs.map{ |s| s[2..-1].split(/\s*:\s*/,2) }.flatten ]
  end
]

require 'pp'
pp hash
#=> {:A=>
#=>   ["definition 1",
#=>    "this is the definition text",
#=>    "definition 2",
#=>    "this is some other definition text"],
#=>  :B=>["definition 3", "this could be: the definition text"]}
```

And a not-purely-functional variation with the same results:

```
hash = defs.group_by{ |s| s[0].to_sym }.tap do |h|
  h.each do |sym,strs|
    h[sym] = strs.map{ |s| s[2..-1].split(/\s*:\s*/,2) }.flatten
  end 
end
```

*Note that these solutions only work in Ruby 1.9 due to the use of `s[0].to_sym`; to work in 1.8.7 you would have to change this to `s[0,1].to_sym`. To make the first solution work in 1.8.6 you would further have to replace `Hash[ xxx ]` with `Hash[ *xxx.flatten ]`*

Comment: breaks my noggin reading it, but +1 for showing a pretty damn cool way

Comment: That is an interesting solution using the nuances of the ruby language.  Thanks for sharing!